# POS Desktop Application using DB or Localfiles ? using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, database, desktop

I am planning to build a POS Application for my shop. I have enough knowledge to build the application using DB and also using local files( system.IO - binary files ) to store and access the data for my application.  But , i have no deployment experience and confused in choosing data storing option.

Database using MDF may be good option ( may ease plenty of coding ) but i don't want to have SQL server on my desktop. as i am using WPF for building , my concern is that my  application may get slow due to server response  and design rendering of WPF.

Then i tried to use only local data (binary files) to store the data and retrive using class and objects. but this coding is taking lot of time , so in the middle of the process i struck in the dilemma of going  back to Database .  Please help  , for performance wise whic one is better . and in Practical World ,in professional applications which one is widely using   .. please give suggestions   ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use SQL Server nor SQL Server Express, you could have a serious look at [SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645984%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), it's very lightweight but quite powerful. In terms of performance, you should not have any problem, but that ultimately depends on how you code :-) and how many items you will store in the database.

Comment: thanks for your suggession.But What is your opinion using local binary / dat files to store the items data. is this a good Idea? if not ,could please tell me the drawbacks ?

Comment: If what you call "data" is actually files or documents created elsewhere or plain blobs (like images), created or updated with other apps, why not, but I suggest you don't reinvent records oriented flat indexed files format. You should find everything you need in existing technology.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/).  It is a light-weight, in-process, SQL engine with widespread use.  The ADO.Net wrapper let's you manipulate SQLite database files using almost any .Net data access technology, and SQLite is widely supported by ORM's.

Comment: +1. And as I understand it, it distributes as a single file in addition to the code obviously.

Comment: Yes, it's a little bit fiddly in my opinion. NHibernate or Lightspeed works nicer with SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two different questions here:  "What database should I use?" is one, and "Should I use a database?" is another.

The first question's pretty easily answered:  For the application you've described, SQL Server CE is almost certainly what you want:  an easily-deployed single-user client-based database that's straightforward to develop for, and whose development tools are built into Visual Studio.

The second question's could be less easy to answer, because in most cases it depends on your application.  But since yours is a point-of-sale application that will presumably be generating transactions continuously as it's used, I think the answer to that is pretty unambiguously "use a database".  If you don't, you'll find very quickly that you've added the task "write a database management system" to your project plan, and do you really have time to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem using files to store the data on the file system, this is how most POS systems work, very few POS systems use databases (at-least this is true for POS systems used in fast food industry).

For 3rd party vendors tho it's a pain in the ass to parse 100's of different formats.

I would go with the above suggestions and use something like SQLCE.